# Rethinkdb point changefeed is not consistent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm working on change feeds, I have an API within which a change feed is triggered. The console.logs within the change feed is printed only when the API is called and that change feed happens. The next time the changefeed occurs nothing happens.

```
exports.trackUser = (id) => {
    return r.table(USERS_TABLE).get(id).changes()
    .then((feeds) => {
        console.log(feeds)
        feeds.each((err, feed) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err)
            }
            if (feed) {
                console.log("change feed")
            }
            })
        })
    .error(logger.error);
}
```

This is the API. In this, once the API is called and then there is an update in the user table, I see the logs. Again if there is an update I don't see the logs. How to make this work each time there is an update in the USER_TABLE? Specific to that ID?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.run(conn)` on the query you've constructed in order to send it to the server.  Unless I'm mistaken and the JS driver automatically runs a query if you attach `.then`.

Comment: Yes `.then` automatically runs the query

Comment: When I run the official JS client library, I get `TypeError: r.table(...).get(...).changes(...).then is not a function`.